# Iionic3 send JWT using ionic-starter-super

Tags: angular, api, ionic3

I save token in local storage, and using ionic-starter-super which have "generic REST Api handler" but I have problem with add JWT token and send it with other data?

Here is example which I try to do that but without any success:

```
post(endpoint: string, body: any, reqOpts?: any) {
  let headers = new Headers();
  let token = localStorage.getItem('token');
  headers.append('Authorization', 'Bearer ' + token);
  this.http.head({headers:headers});
return this.http.post(this.url + '/' + endpoint, body, reqOpts);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I find a solution, maybe someone will have same problem so I post it here how I solve it:

```
 post(endpoint: string, body: any, reqOpts?: any) {
    let token = localStorage.getItem('infloo_token');
    return this.http.post(this.url + '/' + endpoint, body, {
        headers: {'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + token}
    });
}
```

also can be done in other methods like get, put, delete or/and get.

All the best in new Year to all good people in word!

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Ionic 3 with the Angular HTTP Service/dependency >=v4.3, you could take advantage of HTTP Interceptors, which give you some benefits such as less verbose code. Other advantage is the separation of concerns, where the code related to the token will be separated and it can be tested in unit way.

An interceptor is like a middleware which allows you the possibility to add (in that case) JWT token header. An small example:

```
// Interceptor Service
@Injectable()
export class TokenInterceptor implements HttpInterceptor {

  constructor(private authSrv: AuthenticationProvider) {}

  intercept(req: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
    const authToken = this.authSrv.getAuthToken();
    const authReq = req.clone({ 
         headers: req.headers.set('Authorization', `Bearer ${authToken}`) 
    });
    return next.handle(authReq);
  }

}
```

This service will be automatically invoked in each request made to the server.

The last step is to register it in the proper module (providers' array):

```
{
   provide: HTTP_INTERCEPTORS,
   useClass: TokenInterceptor,
   multi: true
}
```